# как получить данные из OkHttp на сервере PHP

Tags: php, android, okhttp

Всем привет! Начал изучать архитектуру клиент-серверного приложения. Клиентская часть использует класс OkHttp3, связывается с сервером и получает ответ. Вопрос заключается в том, как получить данные на сервере.

```
private void getWebService() {


        final RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("lastname", "qwerty")
                .build();

        //String json = "{'lastname:'qwerty'}";
        //RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);


        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.43.110/phpinfo/www").
                //method("POST",RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0])).
                //method("POST",body).
                post(body).
                build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        lastnameF.setText("Failure!!!!!!!");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            lastnameF.setText(response.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            lastnameF.setText("ERROR during get body");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Приведите что у вас в коде на PHP. Код для андроида для сути вопроса, в общем-то и не нужен.

Comment: Сгенерировать страницу на сервере используя GET/POST параметры и отдать ее клиенту

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);
if ($_POST) echo "post";
 else echo "nopost";

var_dump($_REQUEST);
if ($_REQUEST) echo "request";
 else echo "norequest";

var_dump($_GET);
if ($_GET) echo "get";
 else echo "noget";
`  
когда отправляю через html форму все работает корректно